# Showing that $\lg(n!)$ is or is not $o(\lg(n^n))$ and $\omega(\lg(n^n))$

Tags: asymptotics

My instructor assigned a problem that asks us to determine which asymptotic bounds apply to a certain $f(n)$ for a certain $g(n)$, in my case $f(n) = \lg(n!)$ and $g(n) = \lg(n^n)$. For clarity, the convention we use in our class is that $\lg = \log_2$, the "binary logarithm".

I know that by Stirling's approximation, $\lg(n!)$ grows in $O(n\lg(n))$, and evaluating the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n\lg(n)}{n\lg(n)} = C$, some constant > 0, and so $\lg(n!)$ is in $\theta(\lg n^n)$.

$\theta$ also means that my $f(n)$ is is in $O(g(n))$ and $\Omega(g(n))$, but this does not mean that my $f(n)$ is in $o(g(n))$ or $\omega(g(n))$.

For that, I believe I would need to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(n!)}{\lg(n^n)}$, but I am not certain.

What strategy would I use to show that $f(n)$ is in $o(g(n))$ or $\omega(g(n))$? Would I evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(n!)}{\lg(n^n)}$?

Comment: Have you tried evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lg(n!)}{\lg(n^n)}$, using Stirling's formula? Please edit the question to show your result.

Comment: I think so, and was left with $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n\lg(n)}{n\lg(n)}$, which is constant. This convinced me that $\lg(n!)$ is in $\theta(\lg(n^n))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem tot be trying to prove something that is false. If $f=O(g)$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}g/f > 0$ so $f\neq \omega(g)$. Similarly, if $f=\Omega(g)$ then $f\neq o(g)$.

Since you already have that $\lg n! = \Theta(\ln n^n)$, that gives you big-$O$ and big-$\Omega$, which preclude little-$\omega$ and little-$o$, respectively.

Comment: Perhaps a better formulation of my question would be how I might find the tight asymptotic bound of the function $\lg(n!)$? I know that since $f(n)$ is in $\theta(g(n))$, $f(n)$ is in both $O(g(n))$ and $\Omega(g(n))$. I'm really asking how I can determine if $lg(n^n)$ is a tight asymptotic bound of not, or if my function being in $\theta$ makes that a silly question.

Comment: "Tight" usually means big-$\Theta$, since that excludes using $o$ or $\omega$ to squeeze another function between $\lg n^n$ and $\lg n!$.

Comment: Ach, of course! Given a result that concludes big-$\theta$, does that then preclude $o$ or $omega$?

Comment: Yes, because big-$\Theta$ implies big-$O$ and big-$\Omega$, which preclude little-$\omega$ and little-$o$, respectively. (Edited to add that to the answer: the fact that you didn't pick it up means that I was being too oblique!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stirling’s formula.

Or you observe that $n!$ Is the product of $n$ numbers, and of these $n/2$ are at least $\sqrt{n}$, so $\log n! \geq (n/2) \log(n) / 2 = (n \log n) / 4$, which shows it is not $o(n \log n)$.